# Remove duplicates from combined data in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to remove duplicates in one cell where the data is combined from 2 cells. For example :

cell 1 : ABC & DEF
cell 2 : ABC, DEF & LMN

I want both cells 1 & 2 data to combine, which will remove the duplicates at the same time and appear to be : ABC, DEF & LMN in cell 3.

Appreciate if someone can help me on this. Thank you in advance.

***Correction - Sorry if I didn't input the details well. The data are actually names, for example :

Cell 1 : John Mayer & Britney Spears
Cell 2 : John Mayer, Britney Spears & Selena Gomez

The outcome I want in Cell 3 : John Mayer, Britney Spears & Selena Gomez

Meaning that there are spaces in between the words. The commas and ampersand is very important as well.*

Comment: I'd be amazed if someone can do this with a single formula... I'll keep my eye on this and see the outcome.

Comment: Where is @ Scott Craner? Is he on holiday? I will outline a formula solution though.

Comment: Does that include the `&` sign as `ABC & DEF` isn't a duplicate of `ABC, DEF`?

Comment: Sorry, @Darren Bartrup-Cook I don't quite understand what are you trying to ask.

Comment: Sorry - was late in the day and I hadn't read the question properly. I was thinking you meant the entire string of `ABC & DEF` and not `ABC` & `DEF` if that makes sense.

Comment: The entire string is to include "&" and ",". The use of "&" and "," is depending on how many cells are combined. Am trying to achieve : John Mayer, Britney Spears, Selena Gomez - in cell 3 after the combination of : cell 1 that contains : John Mayer & Britney Spears | Cell 2 : John Mayer, Britney Spears & Selena Gomez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpfull untill a formula comes along. Copy paste this into a module:

```
Public Function GetString(STR1 As String, STR2 As String) As String

Dim ARR1() As String, ARR2() As String, ARR3() As String
Dim X As Long, Y As Long, POS As Long

STR1 = Replace(STR1, " & ", ",")
STR1 = Replace(STR1, ", ", ",")
STR2 = Replace(STR2, " & ", ",")
STR2 = Replace(STR2, ", ", ",")

ARR1() = Split(STR1, ",")
ARR2() = Split(STR2, ",")

Y = 0
For X = LBound(ARR1) To UBound(ARR1)
    ReDim Preserve ARR3(Y)
    ARR3(Y) = ARR1(X)
    Y = Y + 1
Next X

For X = LBound(ARR2) To UBound(ARR2)
    ReDim Preserve ARR3(Y)
    ARR3(Y) = ARR2(X)
    Y = Y + 1
Next X

For X = LBound(ARR3) To UBound(ARR3)
    POS = InStr(GetString, ARR3(X))
    If POS <> 0 Then
        If Mid(GetString, POS + Len(ARR3(X)), 1) <> "," Then
            GetString = GetString & ARR3(X) & ", "
        End If
    Else
        GetString = GetString & ARR3(X) & ", "
    End If
Next X

GetString = Left(GetString, Len(GetString) - 2)
GetString = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(GetString), StrReverse(","), StrReverse(" &"), , 1))

End Function
```

Call it like:

```
=GetString(Cell1, Cell2)
```

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JvdV for the help, it doesn't really work well though but i will try to modify along.

Comment: What part of it doesn't work? I'll try help you out if you can provide more information about which part errors out for you. What delimiters are you using? In this example I used "," and "&".

Comment: Currently cell 1 contains : John Mayer & Britney Spears | Cell 2 : John Mayer, Britney Spears & Selena Gomez. Cell 3 came out the result JohnMayer, BritneySpears, SelenaGomez,

But the outcome I want in Cell 3 : John Mayer, Britney Spears & Selena Gomez

Comment: @ ChingLu Tay, Fixed! :)

Comment: Thanks for the modification, but am getting John Mayer, Britney Spears, Selena Gomez, - that ampersand didn't show, and last name is appearing with a comma.

Comment: Really? On my machine it worked perfectly. I'll add a screenshot on how I did it.

Comment: Now I got it. It's the matter of positioning cell 1 & cell 2 in GetString formula. If cell 1 has 2 names and cell 2 has 3 names, it works great. But if cell 1 has 3 names and cell 2 has 2 names, then it came out like what I got previously.

Comment: @ChingLuTay, please try once more! :)

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: @ChingLuTay, Glad I could help. One more small adjustment I made: Old version; If John Mayer was in Cell A1 and John in A2 it would skip John. Fixed that issue now.

Comment: Thanks again @ JvdV !

Answer (score 0):

Try This formula:

```
 =A1&(SUBSTITUTE(A2,A1,""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Pawel Czyz for the help, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

It is do-able by formula. The basic method would be:

- Use the standard split formula from [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/split-text-with-delimiter) but modified so it produces an array of strings.
- Match the array with itself. If the first match is before the current element, then it's a duplicate string and has to be ignored.
- Use textjoin to join the remaining elements.
- Tidy up and work out a way of replacing the final comma with an & sign.

Putting this together first for a single cell containing (say) ABC & DEF

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",true,IF(MATCH(
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),(ROW(Z1:INDEX(Z:Z,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",""))+1))-1)*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1))),
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),(ROW(Z1:INDEX(Z:Z,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",""))+1))-1)*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1))),
0)
<ROW(Z1:INDEX(Z:Z,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",""))+1)),"",
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),(ROW(Z1:INDEX(Z:Z,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",""))+1))-1)*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1)))))
```

But because there are two cells and the delimiters can be "," or "&" every A1 will become

```
substitute(A1&","&A2,"&",",")
```

To get the final "," as an "&", it will be necessary to do the following:

```
=substitute (*entire formula*,",","&",len(*entire formula*)-len(substitute(*entire formula*,",","")))
```

So the only sane way to do this was with a couple of helper cells-

In B1:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1&" , "&A2,"&",",")
```

In C1:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" , ",true,IF(MATCH(
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",LEN(B1))),(ROW($Z1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""))+1))-1)*LEN(B1)+1,LEN(B1))),
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",LEN(B1))),(ROW($Z1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""))+1))-1)*LEN(B1)+1,LEN(B1))),
0)
<ROW($Z1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""))+1)),"",
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",LEN(B1))),(ROW($Z1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""))+1))-1)*LEN(B1)+1,LEN(B1)))))
```

In D1:

```
=substitute(C1,",","&",len(C1)-len(substitute(C1,",","")))
```

Finally I had to test it in Google Sheets because I don't have textjoin in my version of Excel

[image]

Here's how it looks in Excel 2016

[image]

Needless to say the formula in C1 has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @Tom Sharpe, but I don't quite understand how to use the formula that you provided. Do I insert the textjoin formula to *entire formula*?

Comment: I think more practical because of length of formula to use helper cells. Will add it to my answer.

Comment: The formulas are quite lengthy but it does the magic. Thanks @Tom Sharpe